# Angular 8 RXJS Clear Subscription table

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a problem with RXJS. I'm creating a web chat application. Once my web chat lost connection with the Internet, I would like to send my messages after my connection is available. This works fine. What is more, I would like to get messages from websocket, because I need to gather messages which have been sent to me, once I've been offline. This also works fine. My problem is, I would like to firstly CLEAR my messages, and gather them once again. Right now, I gather all messages, but it's concatenating with previous received messages. What I would like to do, is to simply clear, and after clear, place all messages once again to my web chat.

This is my code for messages:

```
this.messages = this.updates.pipe(
  scan((messages: Message[], operation: IMessagesOperation) => {
    return operation(messages);
  }, initialMessages),
  publishReplay(1),
  refCount()
);
this.create
  .pipe(
    map(
      (message: Message): IMessagesOperation => {
        if (message == null) {
          return (messages: Message[]) => {
            return [];
          };
        }
        const newMessage = { ...message };
        return (messages: Message[]) => {

          return messages.concat(newMessage);
        };
      }
    )
  )
  .subscribe(this.updates);
this.newMessages.subscribe(this.create);
```

Here is my method for getting messages:

```
private reconnectAndGetMessages() {
this.reconnectToLastConversation(this.conversationId).subscribe(response => {
  const senderIds = [];
  const getChatMemeberInfoTasks = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < response.entities.length; i++) {
    const senderIdExists = includes(senderIds, response.entities[i].sender.id);
    if (!senderIdExists) {
      senderIds.push(response.entities[i].sender.id);
      getChatMemeberInfoTasks.push(this.getChatMemberInfo(response.entities[i].sender.id))
    }
  }

  forkJoin(getChatMemeberInfoTasks).subscribe(membersData => {
    for (let i = 0; i < response.entities.length; i++) {
      const entityResponse = response.entities[i];
      const chatMemberResponse = find(membersData, (el) => {
        return el.id === entityResponse.sender.id;
      });
      this.loaderService.display(false);
      this.messageService.parseMessageFromReconnect(entityResponse, chatMemberResponse);
    }
    this._showSendMessageConfirmation$.next(true);
  });
}, error => {
  this.firstConnectionWebChat();
});
```

}

I have totally no idea, what to do, to avoid concatenating getting once again all my messages from API, with my previous displayed messages. Appreciate any help, thanks!